# click show dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working facebook style on hover dropdown menu. I think that everything is correct, but the hover menu does not open when I click menu. know I need something missing, but I did not see where I'm doing. Thank you in advance for your help.
 What do I need to click on the menu for the opening

Demo is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7NQ/)

I use it in my work **html code**:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="pay_ayar">
        <a class="account"></a>
        <div class="bubble">
            <ul class="root">
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also i use it in my work **CSS code**:

```
.container {
   float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:90px;
    border:1px solid #000;   
}
.pay_ayar {
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:none;
}
.container:hover .pay_ayar{
     display:block;
}
a.account{
    position:absolute;
    line-height:25px;
    width:20px;
    height:25px;
    cursor:pointer; 
    display:block;
}
.bubble{
   float:left;
    position:relative;
    width:250px;
    height:200px;
    padding:0px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-top:0px;
    display:none;

}
.pay_ayar.open .account { 
                cursor: pointer;
                width: auto;
                display: inline-block;
                padding-left: 7px;
                padding-top: 4px;
                padding-bottom: 4px;
                padding-right: 22px;
                border: 1px solid #AAA;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius: 2px;
                border-radius: 2px;
                font-weight: bold;
                color: #717780;
                line-height: 16px;
                text-decoration: none !important;
                background: white url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% 0px;
            }
            .pay_ayar.open .account {
                border: 1px solid #3B5998;
                color: white;
                background: #6D84B4 url("http://ttb.li/dump/buttons/dropdown_arrow.png") no-repeat 100% -26px;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 2px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
                border-bottom-color: #6D84B4;
            }
```

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/pu7NQ/4/?

Comment: It works just add jquery http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/pu7NQ/5/

Comment: include jquery library..[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7NQ/3/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jquery library **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7NQ/2/)**.

```
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>
```

Comment: Why downvoted? It works fine with jquery library!!... +1

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include `jQuery` by choosing jQuery version from `Frameworks and Extensions` tab of `jsFiddle`

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu7NQ/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery library, Do not use type attributes for style sheets (unless not using CSS) and scripts (unless not using JavaScript).

Specifying type attributes in these contexts is not necessary as HTML5 implies text/css and text/javascript as defaults. This can be safely done even for older browsers.

**html**

```
 <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'><\script>
```